# 1080p PoE IP Camera for NVR

Tags: ip-camera, poe

I have a Lorex NVR and half a dozen of their [1080p PoE (Cat6) IP Cameras](https://www.lorextechnology.com/downloads/ip-cameras/LNB2151/LNB2151_Series_Specs_R2.pdf) that are now over two years old.  Image quality leaves something to be desired, and I'd like to get adjustable lenses so I can fine-tune the field of view.  Features I care about:

1. Best 1080p image quality (although the NVR is set to only record on each at 15fps)
2. Best on-camera low-light illumination
3. Zoom lens so I can manually adjust field-of-view
4. Weather sealed

Answer (score 5):

The [GW 2050IP](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA46G34J5235) seems to be a great buy. $112 and decreased price for bulk buys.

- 1080p @ 2.0MP/30FPS (3.0MP/17FPS) — if you're willing to take a blow to FPS, 3-5 megapixels would do a lot of good.
- Built for outdoor and indoor use
- 42Pcs infrared LEDs for illumination (up to 130ft)
- Optical zoom of 2.8-12mm — the downside here is that as focal length changes, focus changes with it

This model also includes remote connection via a mobile app and noise reduction among other nifty features.